# Tracking down java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in Android

Tags: java, android, debugging

When running my app in Android Studio I am getting an error:

`Throwing new exception 'length=55; index=66' with unexpected pending exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=55; index=66 at void cz.alois_seckar.vseadventrura.DialogueActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (DialogueActivity.java:26)`

The problem is, the error output tells nothing about particular place, where this occurs. I just know it is happening during initialization of my back-end logic class **DemoAppartmentGame**. I am trying to find something problematic inside, but there is a lot of classes depending one on another (and I am not the author of the code). I can't think of anything, that should be array of 55 *somethings* inside the code (there are couple of "rooms" each with couple of "items" inside, no description text appears to be that long).

I even find what I have to do, to overcome it (and it is harming the inner logic, so it is not good solution), but I still don't know **WHY** it is happening, which is what I need to figure out. What I know for sure is, that the code works when running as Java program, but after my port to Android this problem arises.

It is kinda hard to take a wild guess, what is happening, when the app output doesn't specify the place, where the error occurs. I tried to use Android Studio debugger, but found myself to be unable to even get into the code.

The debugger stops on line `game = DemoApartmentGame.getInstance();` (line 26 in `DialogueActivity.java`), but F7 does nothing useful. When I try to put breakpoint inside `.getInstance()`, the debugger never even reaches it...

**My question basically is:** Are there any options to improve application output to see more details for the error?

I am ready to provide more details if needed.

Comment: are you useing any loop using array(55 items),if you use post the loop

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting this exception each time, then If you don't have many choices, One analytical way to do such fishing is to change array to ArrayList one by one. It's quite obvious some where your array is having illegal access, so given current circumstances. This approach will help you dig in code at the same time have a constructive way to solve the issue.

Comment: each time and it also looks like each time with different parameters..last time i got `'length=55; index=6032'`...i really rest my case trying to understand what the hell is causing this, because i would swear there is nothing like that in my code...

Answer (score 0):

You can put break points on exceptions so that whenever any (or a specific) exception is thrown the debugger will stop on the line that is about to throw it.

You can do this in the Breakpoints dialog, click on the plus icon at the top left and select `Java Exception Breakpoint` and then type in ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. (My experience is with IntelliJ but should be the same as Android Studio is based on that).

As long as you have the source for the library throwing the exception it'll take you right to it.

Comment: your solution looks promising, but i still dont feel like it is really helping me :(

Comment: debuger output is still just: `Connecting to cz.alois_seckar.vseadventrura
Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8621', transport: 'socket'
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8621', transport: 'socket'`

Answer (score 0):

**Problem solved:** I have found out it is Retrolambda's fault - or rather my fault. I overlooked the fact, that I have to enable support for default methods in Retrolambda's config in `build.gradle`

The simple code goes like:

```
retrolambda {
    defaultMethods true
}
```

And the error disappeared, the app is running.

So it had to be some internal stuff of misconfigured Retrolambda, therefore unreachable for Android Studio debugging tools...